# Object not found when adding SWITCH statement to query

Tags: sql, switch-statement, ms-access-2007

I have inherited another archaic and inefficient system, and this one uses 5 digit item numbers and sometimes a suffix of 1, 2, or 3 letters as an unique identifier.

The following are all examples of valid item numbers in this field. There are over 20 different suffixes used in total.

```
Item_Num

00001ABC
002ABC
3214
87522ATT
22P
04828P
00421
```

This makes the field difficult to work with, but it's something that cannot be changed. It's an enterprise wide system and too many entities use the field. For a query I am writing, I need to separate the two parts of `Item_Num` into what I am calling `Raw_Num` and `Suffix`. This is made difficult by the inconsistent formatting though; `VAL()` will not grab the "floating" `0s` and `LEFT()` has to grab between 2 and 5 characters. Because of those restrictions, I developed the following code

```
SELECT 
    Q2.Item_Num,
    SWITCH
        (
        VAL(LEFT(("1" + Q2.Item_Num)),1)=1    ,          LEFT(VAL(Q2.Item_Number),5),
        VAL(LEFT(("1" + Q2.Item_Num)),2)=10   , "0"    + LEFT(VAL(Q2.Item_Number),4),
        VAL(LEFT(("1" + Q2.Item_Num)),3)=100  , "00"   + LEFT(VAL(Q2.Item_Number),3),
        VAL(LEFT(("1" + Q2.Item_Num)),4)=1000 , "000"  + LEFT(VAL(Q2.Item_Number),2),
        VAL(LEFT(("1" + Q2.Item_Num)),5)=10000, "0000" + LEFT(VAL(Q2.Item_Number),1)
        )
        AS Raw_Numb
FROM
    (
    [[SUBQUERY]]
    )
    AS Q2
```

In an attempt to get the results of

```
Item_Num    Raw_Num

00001ABC    00001
002ABC      002
3214        3214
87522ATT    87522
22P         22
04828P      04828
00421       00421
```

That however, results in the error `The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object ''`. My search for a solution has taken me to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417626/the-microsoft-office-access-database-engine-could-not-find-an-object), which leads me to believe that somehow I am trying to reference a nameless object. This confusion is doubled when I know I can run

```
SELECT 
    Q2.Item_Num
FROM
    (
    [[SUBQUERY]]
    )
    AS Q2
```

And get the output of

```
Item_Num

00001ABC
002ABC
3214
87522ATT
22P
04828P
00421
```

Which leaves me with three interrelated questions:
Is this just a result of a poorly executed `SWITCH` statement?
Is this because I'm using a `SWITCH` statement in a manner that it can't be used in?
If I'm only referencing `Q2.Item_Num` in the statement, how can I be searching for the object `''`?

And a slightly off topic question for this Stack:
Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: See `OnlyDigits()` in the answer to a similar question: [Strip out non-numeric characters in SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570564/77335).    `OnlyDigits("002ABC")` would give you the string value *"002"*.

Comment: I imagined it was possible in VBA but I hadn't quite committed to solving it that way. You always seem to be the help I need, thanks @HansUp!

Comment: Also, I was able to create `NoDigits()` by changing `/d` to `/D` in the code of `OnlyDigits()`. Regular expressions are beautiful tool that I need to utilize more.

Comment: You're welcome, Fritz.  If you use that function, make sure you get the changes I just made --- the latest version includes `Static objRegExp As Object`

Comment: I picked up the changes you made, thanks again! Have a good day!